# mailchimp audience not updating

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am making a call to the mailchimp api. I receive the following response however when I go into the mailchimp website and check under Audience the subscriber number stays the same.

```
string(3301) " {"id":"0e60c7e290c13409000f350611460a2a","email_address":"patryk@icloud.com","unique_email_id":"fdec69b169","web_id":243007630,"email_type":"html","status":"pending","merge_fields":{"FNAME":"","LNAME":"","ADDRESS":"","PHONE":"","BIRTHDAY":""},"stats":{"avg_open_rate":0,"avg_click_rate":0},"ip_signup":"66.251.171.98","timestamp_signup":"2019-12-03T18:45:22+00:00","ip_opt":"","timestamp_opt":"","member_rating":2,"last_changed":"2019-12-03T18:45:22+00:00","language":"","vip":false,"email_client":"","location":{"latitude":0,"longitude":0,"gmtoff":0,"dstoff":0,"country_code":"","timezone":""},"source":"API - Generic","tags_count":0,"tags":[],"list_id":"925932a4f9","_links":[{"rel":"self","href":"https:\/\/us4.api.mailchimp.com\/3.0\/lists\/925932a4f9\/members\/0e60c7e290c13409000f350611460a2a","method":"GET","targetSchema":"https:\/\/us4.api.mailchimp.com\/schema\/3.0\/Definitions\/Lists\/Members\/Response.json"},{"rel":"parent","href":"https:\/\/us4.api.mailchimp.com\/3.0\/lists\/925932a4f9\/members","method":"GET","targetSchema":"https:\/\/us4.api.mailchimp.com\/schema\/3.0\/Definitions\/Lists\/Members\/CollectionResponse.json","schema":"https:\/\/us4.api.mailchimp.com\/schema\/3.0\/CollectionLinks\/Lists\/Members.json"},{"rel":"update","href":"https:\/\/us4.api.mailchimp.com\/3.0\/lists\/925932a4f9\/members\/0e60c7e290c13409000f350611460a2a","method":"PATCH","targetSchema":"https:\/\/us4.api.mailchimp.com\/schema\/3.0\/Definitions\/Lists\/Members\/Response.json","schema":"https:\/\/us4.api.mailchimp.com\/schema\/3.0\/Definitions\/Lists\/Members\/PATCH.json"},{"rel":"upsert","href":"https:\/\/us4.api.mailchimp.com\/3.0\/lists\/925932a4f9\/members\/0e60c7e290c13409000f350611460a2a","method":"PUT","targetSchema":"https:\/\/us4.api.mailchimp.com\/schema\/3.0\/Definitions\/Lists\/Members\/Response.json","schema":"https:\/\/us4.api.mailchimp.com\/schema\/3.0\/Definitions\/Lists\/Members\/PUT.json"},{"rel":"delete","href":"https:\/\/us4.api.mailchimp.com\/3.0\/lists\/925932a4f9\/members\/0e60c7e290c13409000f350611460a2a","method":"DELETE"},{"rel":"activity","href":"https:\/\/us4.api.mailchimp.com\/3.0\/lists\/925932a4f9\/members\/0e60c7e290c13409000f350611460a2a\/activity","method":"GET","targetSchema":"https:\/\/us4.api.mailchimp.com\/schema\/3.0\/Definitions\/Lists\/Members\/Activity\/Response.json"},{"rel":"goals","href":"https:\/\/us4.api.mailchimp.com\/3.0\/lists\/925932a4f9\/members\/0e60c7e290c13409000f350611460a2a\/goals","method":"GET","targetSchema":"https:\/\/us4.api.mailchimp.com\/schema\/3.0\/Definitions\/Lists\/Members\/Goals\/Response.json"},{"rel":"notes","href":"https:\/\/us4.api.mailchimp.com\/3.0\/lists\/925932a4f9\/members\/0e60c7e290c13409000f350611460a2a\/notes","method":"GET","targetSchema":"https:\/\/us4.api.mailchimp.com\/schema\/3.0\/Definitions\/Lists\/Members\/Notes\/CollectionResponse.json"},{"rel":"events","href":"https:\/\/us4.api.mailchimp.com\/3.0\/lists\/925932a4f9\/members\/0e60c7e290c13409000f350611460a2a\/events","method":"POST","targetSchema":"https:\/\/us4.api.mailchimp.com\/schema\/3.0\/Definitions\/Lists\/Members\/Events\/POST.json"},{"rel":"delete_permanent","href":"https:\/\/us4.api.mailchimp.com\/3.0\/lists\/925932a4f9\/members\/0e60c7e290c13409000f350611460a2a\/actions\/delete-permanent","method":"POST"}]}" {"status":"success"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The status of the request was pending. Pending subscribers are not shown in the mailchimp dashboard.

Comment: LPT: Also check your email quarantine when testing if you have one!!